# Probability of node having a job and leaving?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have following two problem

> I have a system where a node can join and leave at any time. I also have some jobs. I have to assign the jobs to the nodes. So what is the probability that when there are $n$ nodes and $k$ jobs, a node has a job and leaves the system?

In the second system, i have following scenario.

> I have $n$ nodes out among them I have to give $k$ jobs. Now the nodes are further classified into $S$ sets. A set can have any number of nodes(unique nodes). And all the $k$ jobs have to be assigned to any one set. Now the nodes inside the sets are further classified based on their success rate.All the nodes having same success rate are grouped in a class. In a set, there can be any number of classes $C$ having any number of nodes. Now for $k$ jobs for a set $S$  we will assign jobs in the following manner every class $C_i$ will get an equal number of jobs. Now, what will be the probability in this that a node $n_i$getting a job and if any node can leave at any time what is the probability that a node have a job and leaves the system?

## My solution

Then the number of ways you can have the $k$ jobs done is $nCk$.

Now, if a node $p$ has to have a job $j$, then the remaining jobs can be distributed among the remaining nodes in $(n-1)C(k-1)$ ways.

Hence probability is : $(n-1)C(k-1)/nCk = k/n$.

Since any node can leave at any time, without any dependency, we can say that the node working and the node leaving at a certain moment is equiprobable i.e $1/2$.

So, the probability that a node gets a job: $k/n$.

The probability that it leaves: $1/2$.

Therefore the probability that a working node leaves: $k/2n$.

What am I doing wrong, am I doing correctly? Or can I improve something?I am stuck for solving the second scenario? How can I show that in the second case we have less probability that a node haveing a job will leave?
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that a node is assigned a job is $\frac{k}{n}$. The probability that the node is empty is  $\frac{(n-k)}{n}$  Assume the we are in a constant flux of assigning k jobs to  n nodes, then

Thus the proability that a node has a job and leaves the system are independent events and thus would be equal to $\frac{k(n-k)}{n^2}$

Comment: can you please why it is not $\frac{k}{2n}$ @satish ramanathan

Comment: I do not know the context of this problem. Your probability of  $\frac{1}{2} $happens if system enters or leaves the system with no bearing on the assigning of the job to that node.  In my reasoning, these k jobs are reassigned to different nodes in a constant state of flux (network theory) and a node leaves the system means it is idle without a job and a node enters the system means it is assigned a job.  My answer is based on such a notion.  So you may like my answer in the context that I have mentioned here.

Comment: can you help with the second part @satish ramanathan

Comment: I shall try, but after breakfast.

Comment: It would be very helpful @satish ramanathan